# Looking to get the frequency of an int array through a hashmap

Tags: java

```
public int[] topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0 || k <= 0) return new int[0];
    Map<Integer, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int currNum : nums) freqMap.put(currNum, freqMap.getOrDefault(currNum, 0)+1);
```

I don't understand what the `.getOrDefault(currNum, 0)+1);` is doing, but it seems to calculate the frequency properly. I'd like some clearance on this method please and how exactly it's working.

Comment: Have you read the method's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V))? What's unclear about it? Or are you asking how it works in here specifically?

Comment: `put()` is a poor choice; `merge()` is the appropriate choice: `for (int currNum : nums) freqMap.merge(currNum, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);`

Comment: could you explain to me what exactly the ' 1, (a, b) -> a + b' does?

Comment: I read the documentation, but I still had a hard time. I was curious how it works here specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)` method of Map
> interface, implemented by HashMap class is used to get the value
> mapped with specified key. If no value is mapped with the provided key
> then the default value is returned.
>
> **Syntax:** `default V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)`
>
> **Parameters**: This method accepts two parameters:
>
> - `key`: which is the key of the element whose value has to be obtained.
> - `defaultValue`: which is the default value that has to be returned, if no value is mapped with the specified key.
>
> **Return Value**: This method returns value mapped with the specified key, otherwise default value is returned.

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-getordefaultkey-defaultvalue-method-in-java-with-examples/

So, by using that method, first, you're trying to get key's value from the freqMap. If you can find it in map, then you're adding 1 to it and putting it back to freqMap. So, that means that you encountered this key before. Otherwise, that method , `.getOrDefault()`, returns you default value, which is 0, then you're adding 1 to it since you encountered it recently. And putting that value 1 to back to map. So, in the future, when you see that key again, you'll get it's value 1 that you added to the map before, will increase it to 2, and will put it back into the map.

Comment: Makes sense, appreciate the explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. If it means something to you and you feel you get it, you can approve answer then.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static int[] getTopFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
    // build a map: key - number, value - total amount
    Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays.stream(nums)
                                   .boxed()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    // create a PriorityQueue based on Map.Entry. Elements are sorted according to comparator: the
    // most frequent numbers first
    Queue<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> queue =
            new PriorityQueue<>(comparingLong((Map.Entry<Integer, Long> one) -> one.getValue()).reversed());

    queue.addAll(map.entrySet());

    // build final resul
    int[] res = new int[Math.max(queue.size(), k)];

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
        res[i] = queue.remove().getKey();

    return res;
}
```